# Does $G\times H\cong G'\times H'$ imply $G\cong G'$ and $H\cong H'$?

Tags: group-theory

I know that $G\cong G'$ and $H\cong H'$ implies $G\times H\cong G'\times H'$. But is it true for reverse? I mean, does $G\times H\cong G'\times H'$ imply $G\cong G'$ and $H\cong H'$? If so, how to prove that?

Comment: The case when all of the factors are nontrivial and indecomposable is covered by the Krull-Schmidt Theorem, which holds under certain hypotheses, including the case when the groups are all finite. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT-**

$\Bbb{Z_2}\times \Bbb{Z_3}\cong e\times \Bbb{Z_6}$

Comment: Even simpler, $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_1\cong\mathbb Z_1\times\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 7):

You don't even expect that to be true for numbers (i.e., as in $2\cdot 2 = 1\cdot 4$). A more reasonable expectation would be to have a cancelation property, i.e., if $G\times H\cong G\times H'$, does it follow that $H=H'$. This has some chance of being true, and in fact it's a rather deep theorem to classify the groups for which it does hold. What is not so hard (i.e., requiring no deep results, though it's a bit harder than an exercise, unless some instructions are given) is to show that cancelation holds for all finite groups.

Answer (score 3):

Bhaskar's example works (+1), though it is perhaps little unsatisfying.  More generally, it is true that $\gcd(n, m) = 1 \iff \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m \cong \mathbb{Z}_{nm}$; try proving this!

Now choose a number with several prime factors, say $60 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.  Notice that $2^2 \cdot 3 = 12$ and $5$ are coprime.  Likewise, $2^2 \cdot 5 = 20$ and $3$ are coprime.  Hence, we have:

$$\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{20} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \quad ( \cong \mathbb{Z}_{60} )$$

In this manner, one can arrive at many nontrivial examples.